# Selenium Dropdown selection not working

Tags: java, selenium, select, dropdown

Testing firefox with Java via Eclipse IDE.
Below is the HTML code from the website I am trying to test:

```
<td class="selectCommandHolder">
<select id="MainContent_DropDownQueryField" name="ctl00$MainContent$DropDownQueryField" aria-invalid="false">
<option value="ICAO" selected="selected"> ICAO </option>
<option value="IATA"> IATA </option>
<option value="Airfields.Name"> Name </option>
<option value="City"> City </option>
<option value="States.Name"> State </option>
</select>
</td>
```

The default option is the 1st, "ICAO".
Trying to have my test select the 2nd, "IATA" via value.
Selenium java code is below:

```
    WebElement searchOption = driver.findElement(By.id("MainContent_DropDownQueryField")); 

    Select searchIATA = new Select(searchOption); 

    WebElement selected_value = searchIATA.getFirstSelectedOption();
    System.out.println("Selected values is "+ selected_value.getText());

    Thread.sleep(1000);
    searchIATA.selectByValue("IATA");

    if (searchIATA.getFirstSelectedOption().getText().trim().equals("IATA")){
        System.out.println("succesfully selected IATA.");
    } else{
        System.out.println("selected value is not IATA, it is:" + selected_value.getText());
    }
```

For some reason, I am unable to select IATA, even though I believe I am properly trying to target it. My console output looks like this:

```
1487691940734   Marionette  INFO    sendAsync 162acaca-70ac-8e4f-96ff-1b3bd1a5c1ef
1487691940749   Marionette  INFO    sendAsync 162acaca-70ac-8e4f-96ff-1b3bd1a5c1ef
1487691940760   Marionette  INFO    sendAsync 162acaca-70ac-8e4f-96ff-1b3bd1a5c1ef
1487691940769   Marionette  INFO    sendAsync 162acaca-70ac-8e4f-96ff-1b3bd1a5c1ef
1487691940777   Marionette  INFO    sendAsync 162acaca-70ac-8e4f-96ff-1b3bd1a5c1ef
Selected values is ICAO
1487691941789   Marionette  INFO    sendAsync 162acaca-70ac-8e4f-96ff-1b3bd1a5c1ef
1487691941795   Marionette  INFO    sendAsync 162acaca-70ac-8e4f-96ff-1b3bd1a5c1ef
1487691941801   Marionette  INFO    sendAsync 162acaca-70ac-8e4f-96ff-1b3bd1a5c1ef
1487691941822   Marionette  INFO    sendAsync 162acaca-70ac-8e4f-96ff-1b3bd1a5c1ef
1487691941829   Marionette  INFO    sendAsync 162acaca-70ac-8e4f-96ff-1b3bd1a5c1ef
Selected values is not IATA, it is: ICAO
```

I am able to print "allSelectedOptions" and it shows the list of "option values" above. What am i missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thing there is some mistake in your code, You are checking old value in `if condition` Also there is white space in your dropdown value so it is not matching with your `string`

Change your code as bellow and try-

```
searchIATA.selectByValue("IATA");
if (searchIATA.getFirstSelectedOption().getText().trim().equals("IATA"))
 {
  System.out.println("Succesfully selected IATA.");
 }
  else
  {
      System.out.println("Selected values is not IATA, it is: "+ selected_value.getText());
  }
```

**Updated Complete Code**

```
    WebElement searchOption = driver.findElement(By.id("MainContent_DropDownQueryField")); 

    Select searchIATA = new Select(searchOption); 

    WebElement selected_value = searchIATA.getFirstSelectedOption();
    System.out.println("Selected values is "+ selected_value.getText());

    Thread.sleep(2500);
    searchIATA.selectByValue("IATA");
    Thread.sleep(2500);
    System.out.println(searchIATA.getFirstSelectedOption().getText());

    if (searchIATA.getFirstSelectedOption().getText().trim().equals("IATA"))
    {
        System.out.println("Succesfully selected IATA.");
    }
    else
    {
         System.out.println("Selected values is not IATA, it is: "+ selected_value.getText());
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, still the same output: ICAO.
Updated my original post to include this code. Unfortunately no progress

Comment: Are you seeing your changed drop down value on web page ?

Comment: If yes then add `Thread.sleep(2000)` after select the dropdown and check might be taking time to select

Comment: Nope, it does not change when i watch the web browser try and select. I also tried "searchIATA.selectByVisibleText(" IATA ") with the white space, but this throws a "unable to find text" error, so i am still searching by Value "IATA"

Comment: If you are not seeing dropdown value changes then your code is fine as expected . can you try using - `selectByIndex()`

Comment: Using selectByIndex(1), trying to select the 2nd option "IATA" still did not change the ICAO result, however did not throw an error either...

Comment: can you share the URL if possible ?

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot, it is security restricted to the company's IP. But the HTML code in my question is a direct copy from the PageSource

Comment: I have tried with your html snipped, same working here see the updated one

Comment: my result is still ICAO, are you saying that you were able to retrieve IATA with your updated code? If so, it might be something to do with how the website populates these HTML options.

Comment: Yes that's why I was asking for url :)

Comment: Well I guess my only option now is to speak with the developer of the page. I appreciate the help